# What is significance of systemui APK in android?

Tags: android, android-applicationinfo

Sorry for very basic question but could not find the exact answer for it.

Using one application called [AppXplore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonyericsson.androidapp.AppExplore) I am able to see one application systemui.apk (com.android.systemui) on my Nexus5. I want to know what is the use of this APK? What does this apk actually do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SystemUI is the application that controls all the window decor you see on your device. It is a core application running as part of the system framework. The following items are handled/drawn by SystemUI:

- Top status bar
- Notification window shade (and the notifications inside)
- Bottom software navigation buttons (HOME, BACK, RECENTS), if the device has them
- System-level dialogs (e.g. USB Connection Permission or Power Off)

Answer (score 1):

The file has a lot of icons for customizability. You can edit this (through some app or coding ,not sure though) to change the look and feel of your mobile. How to edit this can be found on http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2203166.
Cheers